# Error installing "Contextify" module in node.js in windows 8

Tags: python, node.js, express, visual-studio-2013

I installed jsdom 3.1.2 module which has dependency on contextify. So I am now trying to install contextify but it show error in cmd:
key error:  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft visual studio 2012.0\VC\bin

I already installed python 2.7 and set environment variable name is "Pythonpath" and values is "c:\python27". I also installed MS visual studio 2013 desktop and set the environment variable: variable name is "GYP_MSVS_VERSION" and variable values is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft visual studio 2012.0\VC\bin"

Can somebody tell me where is the problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GYP_MSVS_VERSION` should be set to the version, not the path. So in your case the command would be `set GYP_MSVS_VERSION=2013`.

Comment: thanks @mscdex. It works for me but now the error is different and still the contextify not installed. It show me the error: "Can't find "msbuild.ex". Do you have microsoft visual studio C++ 2008+ installed? ". So, I already installed 2013, what should I do now? thank you